# How to find the nearest date from positive and negative side in SQL and select the required columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I want to select PatID, Indx_date, Ecogvalue, Ecogdate. The Ecogdate should be nearer to the Indx_date. Ecogdate can be 30 days prior to Indx_date and 7days after Indx_date.
INPUT:

```
| PatID | Indx_date | Ecogvalue | Ecogdate   |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 0         | 2020-07-28 |   
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-13 |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-20 |
```

expected output:

```
| PatID | Indx_date | Ecogvalue | Ecogdate   |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-13 |
```

I tried to find the difference btw the dates and converted to positive numbers using abs(). I can find the nearest date but can not get the required columns.

```
| PatID | Indx_date | Ecogvalue | Ecogdate   | diff | pos_diff |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 0         | 2020-07-28 | 6    | 6        |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-13 | -3   | 3        |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-20 | 4    | 4        |
```

I want this as output

```
| PatID | Indx_date | Ecogvalue | Ecogdate   | diff | pos_diff |  
| 1     | 2020-07-22| 1         | 2019-05-13 | -3   | 3        |
```

Comment: `.. ORDER BY pos_diff ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: There are more than one PatID

Comment: We work only with proivided information. Edit the question and make it adequate.